# Why is a viewmodel property get accessor executed on form post?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

ViewModel:

```
    public class IndexViewModel
    {
        public int _SomePropertyExecuteCount;
        public int _SomePropertySetValue;
        public int _SomeMethodExecuteCount;


        public int SomeProperty 
        { 
            get { return ++_SomePropertyExecuteCount; }
            set { _SomePropertySetValue = value;}
        }

        public int SomeMethod()
        {
            return ++_SomeMethodExecuteCount;
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@model ViewModelTest.Models.IndexViewModel

<div>
    <p>@String.Format("SomeProperty executed: {0} times.", Model.SomeProperty)</p>
    <p>@String.Format("SomeMethod executed: {0} times.", Model.SomeMethod())</p>

      <form action="/Home/Index" method="post">
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Models.IndexViewModel model)
    {
        int p =  model._SomePropertyExecuteCount;   // p is 1
        int s = model._SomePropertySetValue;        // s is 0
        int m =  model._SomeMethodExecuteCount;     // m is 0   

        Models.IndexViewModel someOtherViewModel = new Models.IndexViewModel();
        return View(someOtherViewModel);
    }
```

When above code is executed the page indicates that both SomeProperty and SomeMethod were executed one time.
When the page is posted back the value for _SomePropertyExecuteCount indicates the get accessor for SomeProperty is fired during postback.  A breakpoint on said getter confirms this.  Why is the getter accessed when the form is submitted? If the getter needs to be accessed, why does SomeMethod not need to be accessed as well?

Comment: The `ModelState` is inspected after the object is created from the request (post/get) data.  I'm not sure about the entire flow, but the default model binder initiates the call.